# How to resolve gulp watch error

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, babeljs

I am on Windows and running gulp watch from an admin command window.   I am getting the attached error, but not sure how to resolve.  My project structure has not changed or anything so it is unclear why this is happening

[image: gulp watch error]

Comment: I think something missing a node_module or something like taht , can you provide your code snippet .

Comment: I am just running gulp watch and the screenshot shows the output after I make any text change in a javascript file in the folder where gulp watch is watching.